# What is Page lifecycle in tridion

Tags: publishing

Like .net , java page life cycle have some events which help to render page on browser.
I want to know all stages in page life cycle in tridion when we publish it from CMS and it goes to CDA.

it really help full if you give me small brief description of each stage.

Thanks
Bhagat

Comment: Have you read the documentation?

Comment: Hi Dominic , I try to search a document on same but didn't find in sdllivecontent.sdl.com because it's come under troubleshooting section. now i got a link by saurabh and I Will read that.

Answer (score 3):

Below link says about the the cycle of publishing.

http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-B7FB069A-BA94-4018-8B20-D962513BC4E1

([Login is required for the link](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion)))

Answer (score 3):

The publishing stages are the same for any item in Tridion regardless of whether it is a JSP or .NET:

1. A module called the Publisher renders the page text file and places it in a zip called the Transport Package.  This zip also contains metadata and associated binaries such as graphics used on the page.
2. It then sends the file, I.e. Physically transports it) to a module on the CDA called the Deployer.
3. The Deployer receives the zip and based on configuration and instructions within unzips and stores the contents in the appropriate places, such as the document base of your website and Broker Database.

For other details, do have a look at the SDL Live Content Documentation.

Answer (score 3):

While the answers from Nickoly and Saurabh are correct in what they state, I don't think they are answering your question exactly.

The problem is you are comparing a Content Delivery Page object with the SDL Tridion Content Manager Page object.

Technically speaking the CM Page is persisted in the CM storage (database), and a copy of it can be Published to the Presentation Server. There it is stored in the CD storage (could be Broker database or just as an HTML page on disk). So there isn't really a concept of a life cycle like you would have it compared to a Java or .Net Page object in web application.

What I'm reading between the lines of your question is that you want to do something with the Content Manager item that is being published. Maybe you can edit your question and supply that additional information (what do you want to do?), so we can give you a better suited answer?

Comment: Hi Bart.. I don't have specific question Just want basic understanding how page from Content Manager side goes to Content Delivery side. What are the stages and what happen on these stages. I got link , will read that and sure will ask question if i have any doubt.. Thanks a lot Bart.. :)

Comment: @Bhagat in that case I misunderstood and the answers from Nickoly and Saurabh are exactly what you are looking for.